# How to invoke multiple controls in a single thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am fetching data from a database and binding it to 3 different combo boxes simultaneously based on the parent comboBox value. Following is the example, I have three combo boxes named

```
i. comboBoxBranch
ii. comboBoxClass
iii. comboBoxSection
```

Value of comboBoxClass is fetched from database on the basis of selected branch, Similarly the value of comboBoxSection is fetched on the basis of selected branch and selected class. So the order of binding is (ComboBoxBranch) then comboBoxClass and then comboBoxSection.

Now in order to acheive this I am using seperate thread to call GetBranches() method to bind data with comboboxBranch in following way.

```
    private void GetBranches() (This is working perfectly fine)
    {     
        if (comboBoxBranches.InvokeRequired)
        {
            comboBoxBranches.BeginInvoke(((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                comboBoxBranches.DataSource = _schoolManagementSystemServiceClient.GetBranches();
                comboBoxBranches.ValueMember = "BranchId";
                comboBoxBranches.DisplayMember = "BranchName";

            }));
        }
```

Now the problem occurs how should I bind data with other two comboBoxes that are comboxClass and comboBoxSection, Should I use another thread to as I am using for Getbranch Method or there is any other clean method to achieve this. Following is my GetClasses method that I am calling in comboBoxBranches_SelectedValueChanged() event method of comboBoxBranches.

```
private void comboBoxBranches_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Thread thread=new Thread(GetClasses());
         thread.start();  
     }
 private void GetClasses()// in this method how should I achieve invoking  for multiple controls? What should I do here?
    {
           if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            comboBoxBranches.BeginInvoke(((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                Branch branch = comboBoxBranches.SelectedItem as Branch;
            }));
            comboBoxClasses.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate
            {
                comboBoxClasses.DataSource = _schoolManagementSystemServiceClient.GetClasses(branch.BranchId);
                comboBoxClasses.ValueMember = "ClassId";
                comboBoxClasses.DisplayMember = "ClassName";
            });              
        }
    }
```

Same method is for comboxBoxSections whose value is based on both ComboBoxBranches and comboBoxClasses? I am new to multi-threading.

Comment: what is the need for using separate threads?

Comment: there is absolutely no need for separate threads to load 3 comboboxes. just call them asych in order and create an event that loads them Async

Comment: @MohamedNajiullah i am using separate thread because the main UI get stuck for while when comboBoxes are being loaded. I want my application to be responsive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invoking means waiting until the UI thread is idle, then switch to the UI thread and perform some actions. Therefore, the long running task (e.g. querying data from a database) must be performed before invoking takes place.

Today the preferred way to achieve this is to use async/await.

```
private async void comboBoxBranches_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //  We are in the UI thread and can access the controls directly.
    Branch branch = comboBoxBranches.SelectedItem as Branch;

    var classes = await Task.Run(
        // This runs in a new thread. At this point the UI is not blocked.
        () => _schoolManagementSystemServiceClient.GetClasses(branch.BranchId)
    );
    // Here the thread joins the UI thread and returns the classes.

    // We are in the UI thread again. No need for Invoke.
    comboBoxClasses.DataSource = classes;
    comboBoxClasses.ValueMember = "ClassId";
    comboBoxClasses.DisplayMember = "ClassName";
}
```

Note the keyword `async` in the method header. It tells C# to handle this method in a special way. Behind the scenes C# rewrites this method completely to make the magic happen and hides the complexity involved.

To understand how this works, you can imagine that C# puts the lines after the awaited task (the 3 lines with `comboBoxClasses`) into a callback method.

As explained in [Async in depth (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/async-in-depth) you also should rewrite `GetClasses` to work asynchronously and to return a `Task<T>` object, instead of starting a new thread here.

```
var classes = await _schoolManagementSystemServiceClient.GetClassesAsync(branch.BranchId);
```

See: [Asynchronous programming (Microsoft)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what i am trying to achieve is to make my application responsive, i have applied the method you told in the answer but still my main main UI gets stuck for some time and then becomes responsive after the comboboxes are completely loaded. Can you please tell how can i make it responsive so that my main UI doesn't get stuck.

Comment: Time your methods to know where time gets lost (e.g. with a [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx)). async/await helps with I/O operations but not with the UI operations themselves. Those cannot be run in another thread.